# MPG calculator not giving correct answer

Tags: vba, calculator

I am trying to create a MPG calculator in Visual Basic, but it only calculates in whole numbers not decimals. When I input 10 into the gallons section and 375 into the miles section, the calculator only calculates 37 not 37.5.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnCalculateMpg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculateMpg.Click
        'Declare variables for the calculation.
        Dim intMpg As Integer

        lblMpgCalculated.Text = String.Empty

            Try
                'Calculate and display Miles per Gallon.
            intMpg = CInt(txtMiles.Text) \
                    CInt(txtGallons.Text)
            lblMpgCalculated.Text = intMpg.ToString("N")
            Catch
                'Error Message.
                MessageBox.Show("All input must be valid numeric values.")
            End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things: it lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`intMpg` should not be an integer if you don't want to receive a result that's an integer. You may want to use a `Double`, in which case the line where you declare `intMpg` would be:

```
Dim intMpg As Double
```

You also should use the `/` operator for division, not the `\` operator, since the latter performs integral division, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z.aspx).

So, the line where you perform the division should be:

```
intMpg = CInt(txtMiles.Text) / CInt(txtGallons.Text)
```

If you perform these changes, `intMpg` would be a misleading name (since it's not an integer, even though the name makes it sound like it is), so you should change it to something else like `milesPerGallon`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and the info explaining the each part that was wrong. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer`s are only whole numbers. Storing the result of a division in an `Integer` will do an integer division, which means your result will also be an integer and the decimal will get truncated. To get decimals, you should declare your result variable as a `Double`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It did need to be declared a double.